# powershell command to enable/disable logitech unifying dongle

Tags: powershell, usb, kvm, plug-and-play

I'm trying to run the following powershell command as administrator to arbitrarily enable and disable the Logictech dongle for my keyboard and mouse. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
PS C:\> Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "Logitech USB Input Device" | 
where-object {$_.Status -eq "OK"} | 
Disable-PnpDevice -confirm:$false

Disable-PnpDevice : Not supported
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to disable the dongle and later re-enable it.  As you can see with this command I'm receiving an error.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: To disable the receiver itself here it is `FriendlyName : Logitech Unifying USB receiver`

Answer (score 1):

Works for me just how you did it with a M560.

```
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "Logitech*" -Class 'Mouse' | Disable-PnpDevice -confirm:$false
```

Mouse stops working

```
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "Logitech*" -Class 'Mouse' | Enable-PnpDevice -confirm:$false
```

Starts working again.